# builder::sync does not exist error with many-to-many in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.6

Similar issue to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519669/laravel-method-sync-does-not-exist).

And I'm getting the following:

**Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync does not exist.**

But my code already has the given solution...

**Tag Model:**

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Tag extends Model
    {
        public function posts()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post',  'post_tag');
        }
    }
```

**Post Model:**

```
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Post extends Model
    {
      public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
      }

      public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
      }

      public function tags(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag', 'post_tag');
      }
    }
```

**Post Controller**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Session;
    use Carbon\Carbon;

    use App\Category;
    use App\Post;
    use App\Tag;
    use App\User;


    class PostController extends Controller
    {
      public function __construct() { 
        $this->middleware('auth');
      }
...
      public function store(Request $request)
      {

        // Validate the data
        $this->validate($request, [
          'title'       => 'required|max:255',
          'category' => 'required|integer',
          'body'        => 'required'
        ]);

        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->slug = uniqid();
        $post->category_id = $request->category;
        $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $post->save();

        $post->slug = str_slug($request->input('title').' '.$post->id, '-');
        $post->save();

        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);


        Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully saved!');

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
      }
```

A `dd($request->tags)` returns

```
array:2 [▼
   0 => "1"
   1 => "2"
 ]
```

Which are the correct values form the form input.

If I remove the line `$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);` it writes correctly to the DB, and if I don't, but run it anyway, it's saving the to the `posts` table correctly, but not the relevant values to the pivot table.

Comment: There is no `->sync()` method on a `belongsTo` relationship. Judging by the other side of the relationship, you need to make it `belongsToMany` instead. And it should work then

Comment: That was it! I was going over and over the controller, and it was the model that was the issue! Thanks. If you want to answer this, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag', 'post_tag');
}
```

To this:

```
public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'post_tag');
}
```